# Have I actually shown that $X\subset Y$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I'm trying to show that

$$If\ X\cup Y = Y\ then\ X \subset Y$$

I've had a go at a proof but I'm not sure if it actually proves the above at all:

$$Let\ x\in Y$$
$$x\in (X\cup Y)$$
$$x\in X\ or\ x\in Y$$

So we have two cases:

1: $$If\,\,\,\ x\in X\Rightarrow\ x\in Y$$
2: $$x\in Y$$

Hence $X\subset Y$
$\,\,\,\,\,\square$

Sorry if it's very wrong, I've only just started looking at set theory.

Comment: You have to prove that $X \subseteq Y$; thus you have to "start from" $x \in X$ in order to conclude with $x \in Y$ [because $X \subseteq Y$ **iff**  if $x \in X$, then $x \in Y$, for all $x$].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not good. You need to start with an arbitrary $x$ in $X$, then prove it's in $Y$. Here you already started with an $x \in Y$, so you can't prove what you want.

The good argument is :

Let $x \in X$, then $x\in X \cup Y$, this imply that $x\in Y$ because $X\cup Y = Y$